# Variable assignment with ">>" and "&" operators

Tags: python, operators, bitwise-operators

I've been trying to understand a Python script and I can't figure out what this assignment is doing:

```
data_byte2 = value >> 7 & 127
```

I've seen a kind of similar construct with the `or` operator but never with `&` and I have no idea at all what `>>` does (nothing's coming up on Google for it).

Comment: That's bitwise AND (`&`) and right shift (`>>`) - see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: right shift it will shift the bit to right

Comment: ah okay, I think jonrsharpe got the right answer first so maybe make it a question and I'll pick it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`>>`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) is the right bit-shift operator, and [`&`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) is bitwise AND.

This is easier to see if you look at numbers in binary form.

---

```
>>> format(13, "08b")
'00001101'
>>> format(13 >> 1, "08b")
'00000110'
```

You can see that the binary digits are right-shifted by one place (this is equivalent to a division by `2`, so `x >> y` is equivalent to `x // (2 ** y)`). On that basis, `x >> 7` means *"shift `x`'s bits seven places to the right"*, or *"divide `x` by `128`"*.

---

```
>>> format(10, "08b")
'00001010'
>>> format(7, "08b")
'00000111'
>>> format(10 & 7, "08b")
'00000010'
```

Here the output includes a `1` for every bit where both inputs have `1`, `0` otherwise. Given that

```
>>> format(127, "08b")
'01111111'
```

`x & 127` means *"take the last seven bits of `x`"*.

---

As `>>` has higher [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `&`, the expression

```
value >> 7 & 127
```

means *"divide `value` by `128` then take the last seven bits"*.

Answer (score 4):

```
value >> 7 & 127
```

Is like writing:

```
(value >> 7) & 127  # see Python Operators Precedence
```

First you rightshift `value` by 7, then `&` result with 127.

127 in binary is `1111111`, when you `&` with this number, you're clearing all bits on left of the number. For example, if you have 16 bit number:

```
1101011101111101
→
```

Shifting it 7 to the right will result in:

```
0000000110101110
```

`&` with 127 will keep only most right 8 bits:

```
0000000110101110
↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
0000000001111111  & (127)
----------------
0000000000101110
```

Comment: include in you answer, Tell him about the operator priority `>>` has more priority than &

Comment: @Hackaholic It's mentioned in the comment in my answer.

Comment: I just looked this over and it seems like your right shift example differs from jonrsharpe's answer.  How does a right shift of 7 on 1101011101111101 result in 0010011010100110?

Comment: @zoogleflatt typo, the most important thing is that the concept is clear. I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is right shift operator

```
>>> 3 >> 1
1
```

binary of 3 is 00011, now shift one bit towards right the so it will be 00001 so we get answer 1

```
>>> 3 >> 2
0
```

binary of 3 is 00011, now shift two bit towards the right, so it will be 0000, so output is 0